# ¿Cómo hacer un TextView "seleccionable" en Android?

Tags: android, textview

Estoy intentando hacer un `TextView` "seleccionable" en Android, o sea, poder seleccionar párrafos de su contenido, pero no me funciona.

OJO: no quiero que sea un `EditText`, sino un `TextView`.

Este es el XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e5d8bf"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <org.deiverbum.app.utils.ZoomTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Zoomable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
            android:textColor="#272626"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/default_font" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Pero no funciona.

También intenté hacerlo desde el código Java pero tampoco funciona:

```
    mTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

¿Conocen alguna forma de hacerlo?

#### Edición

El `TextView` es personalizado a través de una clase, para permitir aumentar el tamaño del texto con el acercamiento/alejamiento de los dedos sobre la pantalla.

Esta es la clase personalizada en la que está basado el `TextView`, como se puede ver, he intentando establecer el selectable también en los constructores de esta clase, pero no funciona.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class ZoomTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView implements View.OnTouchListener {
    final static float STEP = 200;
    private static final String TAG = "ZoomTextView";
    float mRatio = 13.0f;
    int mBaseDist;
    float mBaseRatio;
    private float zoomLimit = 7.0f;

    public ZoomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setTextIsSelectable(true);
        //    initialize();
    }

    public ZoomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setTextIsSelectable(true);
        //     initialize();
    }

    public ZoomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.setTextIsSelectable(true);
        //       initialize();
    }

    /*
    private void initialize() {
        defaultSize = getTextSize();
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());

    }
*/

    /***
     * @param zoomLimit
     * Default value is 3, 3 means text can zoom 3 times the default size
     */

    public void setZoomLimit(float zoomLimit) {
        this.zoomLimit = zoomLimit;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
/*

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }
*/
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            int pureaction = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            if (pureaction == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
                mBaseDist = getDistance(event);
                mBaseRatio = mRatio;
            } else {
                float delta = (getDistance(event) - mBaseDist) / STEP;
                float multi = (float) Math.pow(2, delta);
                mRatio = Math.min(1024.0f, Math.max(0.1f, mBaseRatio * multi));
                this.setTextSize(mRatio + 13);
            }
        }
        return true;

    }

    int getDistance(MotionEvent event) {
        int dx = (int) (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
        int dy = (int) (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
        return (int) (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy));
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto es lo que pides:

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:text="Hola me llamo Mundo"
    android:longClickable="true" />
```

Activity:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                tv.setCursorVisible(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar. He probado con un `TextView` normal y funciona con solo poner en el XML `android:textIsSelectable="true"`. Pero este textView es personalizado, hice una clase que extiende de `TextView` para poder aumentar el tamaño de la letra con los dedos y es por eso que no funciona. Intenté poner esto en el constructor de la clase: `this.setTextIsSelectable(true);` pero no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente podemos realizar nuevamente la selección del texto en un `TextView`, definiendo a `TextView` la propiedad :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    ...
    ...        
    android:textIsSelectable="true" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto también se puede configurar programaticamente usando el método:

**[setTextIsSelectable(boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setTextIsSelectable(boolean))**

Comment: Si observas mi XML, es justo lo que hago, pero no me funciona. Y con `mTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true);` tampoco funciona.

Comment: Jorge probando con un `TextView` normal funciona, pero este tv es personalizado (depende de una clase que hice para poder aumentar el tamaño de las letras con los dedos). Intenté poner esto en el constructor de la clase `this.setTextIsSelectable(true);` pero no funciona. De todos modos, si lo pongo en el XML debería funcionar ¿no? ¿Alguna idea de por qué no funciona?

Comment: Debería funcionar definiendola en el xml, podría ver la clase custom?

Comment: Jorge, lo he agregado al final de la pregunta. Gracias.